# Node.js Express module exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

im getting this error

> app.get is not a function

this is my config/express.js

```
var express = require('express');


    module.exports = function(){

    var app = express();

    app.set('port',3000);

    return app;

    };
```

and this is my server.js

```
var http = require ('http');

var app = require ('./config/express');


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){

    console.log("Express Server Runing on port"+ app.get('port'));


});
```

what im doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure `require ('./config/express')` is the correct path? If you log `app` does it give you something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in `config/express.js` you export a function but use it as an app. Try this instead:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', 3000);
module.exports = app;
```

Edit: But the following is preferred:

```
/* config/express.js */
var express = require('express');
module.exports = function() {
  var app = express();
  app.set('port', 3000);
  return app;
};


/* server.js */
var http = require('http');
var app = require('./config/express')(); // Notice the additional () here

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Express Server Runing on port"+ app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: thanks this work, i copy my example from a book, maybe the example dont work because its express 3 in book?

Comment: you could also do `var app = require ('./config/express')();` maybe you missed the parentheses from the book

Comment: you are right i miss that, why need to put this ()?

Comment: @John You need an instance of an `express` object. In your book they create a function (usually called a factory function) that returns an instance, so you have to call that function when you need an express object. My first solution shows how to export the express object itself, the second is using a factory.

Comment: what is `module.exports = app;` used for?

Comment: @Rafe OP wished to crete the `app` instance in one file, and then call `http.createServer(app)` in another. To achieve this you have to somehow share either the app instance (example 1) or the factory function for it (example 2)

Comment: How would we do this in typescript ?

Answer (score -3):

Whenever  you  use  Nodejs and  express js  or  anyother    first  check  your  Versions  .  that  can  save a lot of time  . Like if  you move  from express 3  to  express  4    so  you better  check versions